# A movie from the 2000s in which aliens invade the earth on giant 3 legged machines with Tom Cruise as the main character

Tags: story-identification, aliens, alien-invasion

I remember watching a movie that If I am correct, came out in the 2000s (before 2010) in which giant aliens with 3-legged machines invade the earth and Tom Cruise is the main character who has kids he tries to save during the invasion and I remember a blurry ending of an alien dying after being shot by a rocket launcher spitting out some liquid.

I forgot the name of the actual movie and I wanna watch it properly now, can someone help?

Comment: Downvoting this question simply because this answer is very easily Googleable

Comment: @TenthJustice Sure thing, I don't really care much, I found my movie (so I am happy now) that I wasn't able to find by Googling.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan I'm genuinely curious - what did you enter into your google search?

Comment: Literally posting this question's very title into Google shows the result

Comment: @AncientSwordRage "Tom cruise alien movie" showed me a movie called "oblivion" :/

Comment: @MaëlNison True but I thought of the title and started typing it while asking the question, I did not thought at all that Google would recognize such a long search, my bad of course.

Comment: We live and we learn ☺️

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Yep!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [*War of the Worlds*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407304/), a 2005 remake of the classic film [*The War of the Worlds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds_(1953_film)).

> An alien invasion threatens the future of humanity. The catastrophic
> nightmare is depicted through the eyes of one American family fighting
> for survival.

Comment: Yes! this is the one, I'll accept the answer after the 7 minutes timer is gone.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan - Glad to be of help. Purely as an aside, why not watch the (better) original film instead?

Comment: I'll try to watch both then because the remake film which I watched when I was a kid is blurry in my mind but I always wanted to watch it again.

Comment: @Valorum I actually very much enjoyed this version.  The 1950s one I recall didn't even have Wells's tripods, the Martians had floating crescent-shaped pods.

Comment: There is also the BBC miniseries, which was pretty good.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-yas0yPbLU

Comment: And of course there's the excellent album by Jeff Wayne - "Jeff Wayne's Musical Version of The War of the Worlds."

Comment: And maybe someone might actually want to read the original novel by H.G.Wells.